# Website template is not fitting together correctly

Tags: html, css, templates, web

I'm designing a website, and I'm working on a simple navigation bar. "home,gallery,about us, etc..."

Anyway when I start to code the navigation bar, there are gaps in between the links "home,gallery,about us, etc...." when it is suppose to have no gaps and be connected from beginning to end. **So my question is why is this happening?** it's suppose to look like this:

```
  ----------------------------------
  |home|about us|gallery|contact us|
  ----------------------------------
```

instead I get:

```
   -----   ----------  -------- -----------
   |home   |about us|  gallery| contact us|
   -----   ----------  -------- -----------
```

That's the best I can do with out showing the real page, so hopefully these examples suffice. I've tried everything, all the buttons are 128 x 58 pixels and I tried setting the table width & height many different ways as well as  too, I just don't know why I'm getting these gaps. **What could I be doing wrong?** Just to make things clearer and easier to understand here is the link to my navigation bar. http://krat0s.x10.mx/

here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/4Dsv0ish

Comment: Where is the code? Are we just supposed to post *guesses* of what the problem might be, so you can tell us *"that's nothing like what I'm trying to do"*?

Comment: Yes I can, cuz it's nothing like what I'm trying to do, besides I'd doubt you'd even know where to start

Answer (score 3):

Html

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>home</li>
    <li>about us</li>
    <li>gallery</li>
    <li>contact us</li>    
</ul>
```

Css

```
#menu li { float:left; width:128px; height:58px; background:red; text-align:center; }
#menu li:hover { background:green; cursor:pointer; }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DrUhA/

Comment: that's nothing like what I'm trying to do

Comment: If you read your questino you need to buld navigation bar with buttons on it without any gaps between buttons. That's what I've done in example. Please clarify it if I'm wrong.

Comment: here this will make it easier to under stand, here is what I'm working on. http://krat0s.x10.mx/

Comment: So? you need put what I've written to the div with your background. http://jsfiddle.net/DrUhA/2/. But it's without images and probably need some tuning

Answer (score 2):

Using your link you posted in an above comment (krat0s.x10.mx) its due to the fact you are not setting `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` to `0`

For your table which contains the navigation bar change the opening table tag to this

```
<table width="55%" height="58" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

That is the quick fix, but I would probably suggest you do not use tables for your layout, unless you are going to display tabular data as it is bad practice and if frowned upon by most web designers, look in to using divisons `<div>` and lists:

```
<ul>
    </li></li>
<ul>
```

Similar to what Samich has suggested, it may take more time to learn how to code this way but it is a much better method.

**Some links for you**

[W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) - Will teach you most of the different tags and their uses as well as some basic tutorials.

[Tizag](http://www.tizag.com) - I used this more to practice PHP but they have a few HTML tutorials.

Sorry I can't really provide more links as the way I learnt my HTML and CSS was mainly from random tutorials and trail and error and that was many years ago. For tableless layouts you will want to look in to things such as the CSS properties: `float` `clear` and `position`. A quick [google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tableless%20layout%20tut) brings up a bunch of tutorials you can try though!

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks alot, I will take your advice, and you fixed my problem perfectly.

Comment: @nastyn8 Hi, I can't really suggest any as I didn't use any myself, I have updated my answer with a couple of links though, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I would just try to add `cellspacing="0"` and `cellapdding="0"` to your table tag. That should to the trick

```
 <table width="55%" height="58" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

hth

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

If it doesn't work, then probably it's the `<td>`'s padding:

Then do:

```
td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

If it doesn't solve the problem, then apply all of them:

```
table, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

As *Rawb92* suggested, avoid using tables for layout.
In your case, a *list* is more *semantically-correct* markup in your navigation.